# Unable to execute callback function as its is not being passed correctly

Tags: node.js, callback

```
exports.Instance = function(args, callback){
  valargs(array, function(err){});
}

function valargs(array, callback){
  callback(null);
}
```

callback in valargs function is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In the given code sample the `callback` attribute of `valargs` is defined. It is `array` being undefined in both `Instance` and `valargs` scopes that cause the TypeError you seee.

Substituting the unbound reference with a stub empty array make the example execute without errros. Open your browser console to see the relevant `console.log` output.

```js
Instance = function(args, callback) {
  valargs([], function(err){});
}

function valargs(array, callback){
  console.log(array, callback)
  callback(null);
}

Instance();
```